# Cache Types are Invalid. How can i resolve this permanently?

Tags: magento2, php, cache, magento2.3.4

Error: One or more of the Cache Types are invalidated: Configuration, Page Cache. Please go to Cache Management and refresh cache types. 
How can i resolve this permanently?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't ever want to clean cache manually, there is a watcher developed by [Vinai Kopp](https://github.com/Vinai) which will clean it for you when the cache invalidates. Just a heads up that it is developed in node js so you'll have to install that to run it.

You can find the documentation and source of the watcher here - https://github.com/mage2tv/magento-cache-clean

Answer (score 0):

Is not an issue , but a magento notice . 
When you make updates on admin , you need to clean cache configs.
You need to Flush Magento Cache

```
System -> Cache Management ->  Flush Magento Cache
```

[image]

If you dont want those messages to show up in the admin :

You need to disable **Magento_AdminNotification** module .

Check this for more https://blog.landofcoder.com/disable-magento-2-admin-notification/

Comment: Every time we have to do this ? Is there any automation in that ?

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: I would advise against disabling admin notification as this will affect other modules to, instead look at removing the cacheOutdated message from the messagelist https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/AdminNotification/etc/adminhtml/di.xml#L13

Answer (score 0):

Make sure whether you have nodejs

The following instructions may be helpful to you.

Global Installation: composer global require mage2tv/magento-cache-clean

PATH Setting:

1. Open terminal run

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

2. Add the following command at end of the line.  (this may differ in your system)

```
   export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"
```

3. Save and close the file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to solve here. Magento will flush the caches according to its own logic, as long as cron jobs are correctly configured on the server.

If you must have changes reflected on the frontend immediately, you can flush the caches manually. However, frequent cache flushing defeats the entire purpose of the cache and reduces performance for front end users.